# Registering COM referenced DLLs on a build server

Tags: c#, msbuild, interop, continuous-integration, com-interop

We're developing a C# application that references a few COM libraries (AutoIT for example).

I am including all referenced components under source control, in a 3rd party "Libs" folder.

The problem is that COM dll's don't have a HintPath property in the .csproj file, and i assume these must be manually registered using regsvr32 (or using a script of some sort).

I am currently looking into creating an MSBuild script that will run before every build, however i couldn't figure out if i should be manually calling regsvr32.exe or use some predefined MSBuild task?

Currently, this is what i've attmpted as a test:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Build">
  <ItemGroup>
    <MyAssemblies Include="D:\*.dll" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="Build">
    <RegisterAssembly
      Assemblies="@(MyAssemblies)" >
    </RegisterAssembly>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

This generates errors that the DLLs i've placed in the given folder are not valid DLLs.

What is a good solution for this problem?

EDIT:

Projects that reference COM dlls have something similar to this in the .csproj file:

```
<COMReference Include="AutoItX3Lib">
      <Guid>{F8937E53-D444-4E71-9275-35B64210CC3B}</Guid>
      <VersionMajor>1</VersionMajor>
      <VersionMinor>0</VersionMinor>
      <Lcid>0</Lcid>
      <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
      <Isolated>False</Isolated>
    </COMReference>
```

This does not include any hint path as other managed assemblies, so on a build server, the referenced COM dll is not found.

When registering the COM dll on the build server using REGSVR32, the build succeeds.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't register COM servers on a build server.  That's only required when you actually want to *run* the compiled code.  What you need is the type libraries for the COM servers so you can get the interop assemblies.  Which you create with Tlbimp.exe.

Whether you want to run Tlbimp on the build server or up front on a dev machine depends a great deal on how you deploy these COM servers.  Keeping a copy of the COM executables and .tlb files very close to your interop libraries is a good idea.  In other words, check them in.  The installer can now retrieve a known-good version of the COM server as well.

Comment: I have both the type libraries and the interop assemblies checked into my source control (Git). Referencing the interop is not enough though. What is the output of Tlbimp? i rather do it as part of the build process rather than up front, since when upgrading the build env, i could just copy off all scripts and expand to more servers and having all the logic stored there with no prerequisite steps

Comment: Output of Tlbimp is the interop assembly.  I can't do anything with "is not enough", you'll have to describe the build error you get better.

Comment: i have updated my original question. Interop dll exists in the "dependencies" folder, however there's no linking between the .csproj and this file, so the build is not picking this file up. On my dev envinronment, this works fine as i have the original software package installed (AutoIt for example), however on the build server this is not installed and so the build fails without doing some extra step prior to compiling..

Comment: Remove the reference from the project.  Add it back with the Add Reference + Browse tab, selecting the interop assembly.  You'll now have a regular `<Reference>` instead of a `<COMReference>`.  With a HintPath.

Comment: I will try that. I wonder why the process works the other way by default (adding a reference to the COM library adds a COMReference, and not a reference to the generated Interop)

Comment: Also i will dig MSDN or any other good resources on Interoperability as i seem to not have a solid knowledge on that area.

Answer (score 16):

For my original answer to a similar question see: [TFS Build server and COM references - does this work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8887087/745414)

A better option for build servers may be to use the `COMFileReference` item in your project file instead of `COMReference`. An example would look like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <COMFileReference Include="MyComLibrary.dll">
     <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
   </COMFileReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

The COM dll doesn't need to be registered on the machine for this to work.

Each COMFileReference item can also have a WrapperTool attribute but the default seems to work fine. The EmbedInteropTypes attribute is not documented as being applicable to COMFileReference, but it seems to work as intended.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-items#comfilereference for a little more detail. This MSBuild item has been available since .NET 3.5.

Comment: BTW, it appears that HintPath works for the COMReference task as well even though it's not documented.

Comment: HintPath didn't work for me in COMReference, but I could use a path in the Include attribute of COMFileReference.

Comment: @jpierson I think they are fixing the documentation now: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/issues/2265

Answer (score 0):

1) Try to reference the COM libraries to your csproj as references - if you haven't done so.

2) Try to append to your csproj file:

```
<Project ... >
    ...
    <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
        <Exec Command="regsvr32.exe yourComponent.dll" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

PS: if you are using some sort of build server software you should not modify the csproj but the script used by the build at the server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I prefer to not alter the .csproj files, but rather have one "prep" script to do this work. I'd like to run regsvr32.exe on ALL assemblies (maybe place all COM references under a single folder and run it on them). How do i iterate on all of them one by one in MSBuild though.

Comment: I believe i found the solution - using the %(MyAssemblies.Identity) notation will run the command once per each of the expanded files when using *.dll . Is this correct and common usage?

Comment: I don't really understand you solution with %(MyAssemblies.Identity) as you are trying to use COM dlls. But to iterate through list files you may use 'for' in the command line if you'd like: to find out how to use it - just type 'for /? > yourTargetPath\help_for_for.txt' and read the created txt file.

Comment: I know it's possible from cmd line, however our CI server (TeamCity) offers an MSBuild runner, running it as a for command line execution would be more cumbersome. Also, MSBuild gives better reporting and logging, and lastly, this will be a part of a larger MSBuild script.

Comment: I didn't mean to run whole build in cmd - but vice versa to include cmd batch as part of execution in msbuild.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if there's any task in MSBuild, to call regsvr32, but REgisterAssembly is calling regasm.exe - that is - registering .NET components for COM interop.

I am sure, that just calling regsvr32 manually would be the fastest way to achieve the desired result.

Another thing is - what will happen if the COM DLLs are already registered by the previous build and you'll run your build script again? (I don't really know how the regsvr32 will react, just a thought here)

Comment: Calling regsvr32 again is harmless (AFAIK), except for wasted X milliseconds of time.