# Using `COMFileReference` instead of `COMReference` for automated builds?

Tags: c#, jenkins, windows-mobile, continuous-integration, tlbimp

I'm trying to put a Windows Mobile 6.0 C# project on our continuous integration server (Jenkins).

There's an error when trying to compile the project, which references a TLB:
`ResolveComReferences` always return `TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED`.
Even when passing the project between different devs, references must be added again.

I found something regarding a change which can be done the the project file, using `COMFileReference` instead of `COMReference`.

Is there a way to solve this without modifying the .csproj file?

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498258/tfs-build-server-and-com-references-does-this-work help?

Comment: while it does help, i was looking for a way to do it without modifying the project file, if possible at all (maybe something in jenkins project configuration like an extra build step)