# COM References and TFS build definition

Tags: visual-studio-2013, com, msbuild, tfsbuild

I have a C# project in which I have a COM Reference. It compiles fine when opened in VS 2013. But, it fails as part of TFS build definition.

TFS version : 2013
TFS Build Controller & Agent : 2013
VS version : 2013

The failure message says that it could not find the Interop dll. I cannot manually create the Interop dll and check-in into TFS because it would keep changing and I want my C# project to always take the udpated COM reference.

I tried the [COMFileReference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498258/tfs-build-server-and-com-references-does-this-work) suggestion but it did not solve my issue. I even manually registered the COM dll using regsvr32 but still I am facing the issue.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Regards,
kvk1985

Answer (score 5):

A COM reference is the safest way to ensure that your program matches the actual installed component when you test your code.  The compiler will read the type library of the component, a very similar mechanism that's used for normal .NET assembly references. Except that the type definitions come from the type library instead of .NET metadata.

But has a disadvantage in your case, it can only work when the component is actually installed on the machine.  That probably did not happen on that build server.  That's fairly normal, the people that maintain build servers don't particularly like anybody messing with it.  And it is a maintenance headache, the build breaks when the devs update their machine with the latest version but forget to update the build server as well.  And old builds get to be hard to reproduce.

So installing the component on the build server is the Quick Fix.  If that's an insurmountable obstacle then somebody needs to run Tlbimp.exe on their machine.  That generates the interop assembly, it needs to be checked-in to source control.  And the project must be modified, remove the COM reference and add the reference to the generated interop library.  It will now build the same way on the build server and the dev machines.

That's of course brittle the other way, if a dev updates the component on his machine then there will be a mismatch with the interop assembly.  That can be a very ugly one, an E_NOINTERFACE runtime error if the COM vendor did it right, something excessively nasty like calling the wrong method, a stack imbalance or an AVE if he didn't.  Otherwise the exact same kind of failures that can occur if the user's machine doesn't have the right version of the component installed.  Standard DLL Hell.

You'll have to make the call yourself, there's no One Right Answer.

Comment: As a build engineer, I support your second solution (running tlbimp against the COM component). but you're correct it does depend on circumstance.

Comment: Thanks, Hans for the reply. I am thinking of one way. Correct me if I am wrong. How about adding in the pre-build event, the step of converting the COM component to Interop assembly using tlbimp.exe.

Comment: It is technically possible, but making the setup procedure between the dev machines and the build machine isn't a very good idea.  The devs are not going to be happy about it, bogs them down for no benefit, and the component still needs to be present on the server.