# How to make COMReference work in Azure CI/CD pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines, csproj, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have used a dll to my project which gets added to my project file as a `COMReference` like following

```
<COMReference Include="GENERALCREDITREQUESTMANAGER450Lib">
  <Guid>{BDB6DDB5-5C02-492F-954E-68ED3D8F075D}</Guid>
  <VersionMajor>1</VersionMajor>
  <VersionMinor>0</VersionMinor>
  <Lcid>0</Lcid>
  <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
  <Isolated>False</Isolated>
  <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
</COMReference>
```

Now the problem is it fails during my pipeline build, saying `Namespace or type GENERALCREDITREQUESTMANAGER450Lib can't be found` which is understandable because unlike other references it doesn't have any `HintPath` to locate the dll.

After looking around a bit I found this [article](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/access-to-com-library-from-pipeline/1052521) that basically says use tlbImp to generate the dll and then reference that dll using the following syntax:

```
<Reference Include="GENERALCREDITREQUESTMANAGER450Lib">
  <HintPath>InteropAssemblies\GENERALCREDITREQUESTMANAGER450Lib.dll</HintPath>
  <EmbedInteropTypes>true</EmbedInteropTypes>
</Reference>
```

But if I do that then my visual studio build fails, because then VS can't find the namespace even though it's added to the reference. One of the post suggested to use `COMFileReference` instead of `COMReference` but that ends up with same "Namespace not found" error.

How can I make the pipleline working?

Comment: when you used `tlbImp` manually, did you use its `/namspace:GENERALCREDITREQUESTMANAGER450Lib` option? - [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/tlbimp-exe-type-library-importer)

Comment: @MartinUllrich: That was it! Thanks a lot! If you post that as answer I will accept that as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `COMReference` item requires the library to registered on the build server which may be hard to do depending on the environment.

The way to use `tlbimp` locally and add the generated .dll to the project sources is likely more compatible for your setup though it requires you to pass the namespace as a parameter (`/namspace:GENERALCREDITREQUESTMANAGER450Lib`) to achieve the same result as the `COMReference`.

Comment: Note for future users. ComFileReference also works after using /namespace