# How do I get TFS teambuild to build c#>VB6>c# application (ComReference prob?)

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild

I'm trying to get TFS team-build to reliably build a WPF C# app. This app relies on a VB6Lib.dll which we maintain, this VB6Lib.dll itself relies on other C# libs that we also maintain.

I've set up a build definition to build (in order):

- VbDependencies.sln (all libs in this have com interop set, thus the VB6 can find their TLBs)
- buildVB6Lib.proj (an msbuild file which calls "VB6.exe /make /d" to make the VBLib.dll on the build server, as part of this script I've been copying the VB6Lib.dll output to C:\tmp)
- MainApp.sln (in my workspace, I've added a reference to C:\tmp\VB6Lib.dll)

Does this sound ok
?
On my dev laptop I usually build the VB6, copy its output to \tmp and then regsvr32 it there before adding a reference to it in my C# solution. It's this step that I'm not convinced my build def is doing.

Also, is there a way to get more useful output from the VB6 build, currently I get "Compile Error in File 'xxx.bas' Can' find project of library", but not which actual library it can't find.

Comment: I think it's the ComReference field that's incorrect in my MainApp.sln ? and I think this question is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460910/registering-com-referenced-dlls-on-a-build-server

Comment: Afraid I'm not familiar enough with the VB6 build process any more to answer the second part of your question. You may want to consider re-posting just that question with a different set of tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in that the critical point in your build process on the development system lies in registering the COM object. However, one does not in general want to register the COM object on the build server, as this can cause all kinds of versioning issues and silent failures when the wrong COM object is registered or the registration fails.

The proper way to accomplish this is to generate an interop assembly manually and reference that instead of the COM object. This is accomplished with the tlbimp utility, for instance:

```
tlbimp ..\Libraries\VBLib.dll /out:..\Libraries\Interop.VBLib.dll
```

Run that command on your development system, then remove the reference to VB6Lib.dll and add a reference to Interop.VBLib.dll. You can then add the tlbimp command as a prebuild event in the referencing project so that the interop assembly is always build from the correct version, and you will never again need to have your COM object registered on the build system.

Comment: how is this interop different from the interop that VS generates for you when you reference an ActiveX/COM lib in the solution?

Comment: This was useful to me when using the Hosted TFS - my COM object was (obviously) not registered on the build server.