# difference between reference and COMREFERNCE elements in .net

Tags: c#, .net

What is difference between

```
<reference/> and <comreference />
```

.

CS Project i loaded into visual studio 2013 these comreference specified dll files are not resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<comreference />` requires the library to be registered on your system as a COM server, e.g. with `regsvr32`, while `<reference/>` is just for normal non-COM references. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629388.aspx).

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7461172/682111) for `Tlbimp.exe` info. [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8887171/682111) on that page mentions `COMFileReference` which you can also try.